# How to close a while loop using user input for doubles

Tags: java, while-loop, average

So, disclaimer, this is for a class, but I've already submitted the homework and reached out to the professor for assistance, so I'm not cheating or asking someone to do my homework.  I spent hours trawling through this site, in the process, as well.

I am trying to get user input for up to 52 times, add them all together and then average the sum.

I made this method to allow the user to input their weekly profits, based on the Sales variable input further up in the code.  I thought a limit of 52 would be good, as it would allow a person to average 2 wks, a month, 6 months, etc, like if they’re trying to budget or find an estimated yearly earnings.

```
    //new method
    public static void computeAverageSalesProfit() {       

        //new scanner object in method
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //new object
        Sales AvgProfit = new Sales();

        //prompt for input
        System.out.println("Please enter weekly profits, up to 52 weeks.  When finished, enter '-1.'");       

        //value to store input, and test against
        double value = 0;
        //new double array to sum together and average out
        double[] sum2 = new double[52];

        //while loop of doom
        while(value >= 0) {

        for (int i=0; i<sum2.length; i++) {
        value = input.nextDouble();
        sum2[i] = value + 0;

        }
        }

        double WeeklyProfits = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<sum2.length; i++) {
            WeeklyProfits = sum2[i] / sum2.length;
        }

        AvgProfit.setWeeklyProfits(WeeklyProfits);

        System.out.printf("Your average profits are %.2f", AvgProfit.getWeeklyProfits());

    }
```

This is the code I ended with for the night, and I cannot figure out how to end the while loop.  I didn’t originally have the value variable, but thought that a check for it before the sum2 iteration would allow me to close it.  When I run the program, it takes in user input, but never ends until I hit 52 iterations.  I also tried using "0000" in a boolean expression, but that didn't work, either.

I also tried without setting the value variable, I’ve tried every way I can think of and can find on the internet.  I tried with and without a value variable with just a plain double (not array).  I even tried with a String, using a boolean expression (good = true/false, while (!/good), etc, but I was unable to convert to double and average it out.

I’m completely baffled, and my head hurts. I would really appreciate any assistance or insight you’re able to share.  Thank you.

Oh, and I have a while loop in a different part of my code that does work, but I don't think this one works the same way.  I think I'm either overthinking it, or just missing something very obvious.

```
//Check Year length separate, keeping original code mostly intact
    public static boolean isValid(String input)
    {
        //Does it have 4 digits?
        if(input.length() != 4)
            return false;

    // Is it a number ?
        try
        {
            Integer i = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Passed all checks and is valid
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Looking at your code, I think the while loop only terminates, when `value` is less than 0. However, since you update value 52 times, the 52nd time you enter a variable has to be less than 0.

Comment: I think what you want is the user to be able to enter up to 52 numbers, but not more. However, if he only wants to enter 42 numbers, he has to explicitly notify the program, that he is done entering numbers. This can be done in different ways - reading an "exit" line or "" empty line (aka. 'enter'). You have to implement this in your code however.

Comment: I missed a bit of your code, you got the thing with the exit code (here '-1'). The while loop is unnecessary then. If you read a false value aka. '-1', just call `break;`. This will exit the for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you could do is to instead of using a while loop use the for loop like this:

```java
//value to store input, and test against
double value = 0;
//new double array to sum together and average out
double[] sum2 = new double[52];

// repeats 52 times max
for (int i=0; i<sum2.length; i++) {
    value = input.nextDouble();

    // Checking if the user entered a negative number
    if (value < 0) {
        // The break keyword exits a loop
        break;
    }

    sum2[i] = value + 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!  I was overthinking it...  I was trying to use a loop that was unnecessary.  Now, I have another question for you...  My avg (WeeklyProfits, yes, I need to lowercase the first letters of my variables) spits out 0.  It's in my original code.